# How to check for continuity minding possible gaps in dates

Tags: r, date, group-by

I have a big data frame with dates and i need to check for the first date in a continuous way, as follows:

```
ID   ID_2  END         BEG
1    55    2017-06-30  2016-01-01
1    55    2015-12-31  2015-11-12  --> Gap (required date)
1    88    2008-07-26  2003-02-24
2    19    2014-09-30  2013-05-01
2    33    2013-04-30  2011-01-01  --> Not Gap (overlapping)
2    19    2012-12-31  2011-01-01
2    33    2010-12-31  2008-01-01
2    19    2007-12-31  2006-01-01
2    19    2005-12-31  1980-10-20  --> No actual Gap(required date)
```

As shown, not all the dates have overlapping and i need to return by ID (not ID_2) the date when the first gap (going backwards in time) appears. I've tried using for but it's extremely slow (dataframe has 150k rows). I've been messing around with dplyr and mutate as follows:

```
df <- df%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(END_lead = lead(END))

df$FLAG <- df$BEG - days(1) == df$END_lead

df <- df%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 filter(cumsum(cumsum(FLAG == FALSE))<=1)
```

But this set of instructions stops at the first overlapping, filtering the wrong date. I've tried anything i could think of, ordering in decreasing or ascending order, and using min and max but could not figure out a solution.

The actual result wanted would be:

```
ID   ID_2  END         BEG
1    55    2015-12-31  2015-11-12 
2    19    2008-07-26  1980-10-20
```

Is there a way of doing this using dplyr,tidyr and lubridate?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "gaps"... There are seemingly gaps everywhere? Also, does "backwards in time" means from top to bottom in your df?

Comment: @FonsMA "Backwards in time" mean from the biggest date to the lowest (the df is ordered that way) so yes from top to bottom. The gaps that you are seeing are either a day difference (not considered gap) or an overlapping. Every beginning of one is the end of the previous plus one (or an overlapping of the dates)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, except that the one marked as "no actual gap" seems to have the largest gap of all?

Comment: @FonsMA Sorry,thats my mistake, i'll edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(END, BEG), funs(as.Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(BEG > ( lead(END) + 1 ) | is.na(BEG > ( lead(END) + 1 ))))
```

With your last data, it gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  ID_2 END        BEG       
  <int> <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1    55 2015-12-31 2015-11-12
2     2    19 2005-12-31 1980-10-20
```

What the solution does is basically:

- Changes the dates to `Date` format (no need for `lubridate`);
- Groups by `ID`;
- Selects the highest row that satisfies your criteria, i.e. the highest row which is either a gap (`TRUE`), or if there is no gap it is the first row (meaning it has a missing value when checking for a gap, this is why `is.na(BEG > ( lead(END) + 1 ))`).

Comment: Thank you, i still lack the knowledge of the combinations available in the packages (in this case `mutate_at(vars(END, BEG), funs(as.Date)` or `slice(which.max`

Answer (score 0):

I would use xts package, first creating xts objects for each ID you have, than use first() and last() function on each objects.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet